# pydantic - json keys are not valid python field names

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a json with keys containing characters that a python field name can't contain:

```js
{
  "mlflow.source.git.commit": "fbe812fe",
  "other.key": "other.value"
}
```

How to use `pydantic` to parse such a json? I'd like to give it an alias and actual key name, like

```py
class Tags(pydantic.BaseModel):
  commit = field(key="mlflow.source.git.commit", type=str)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using `pydantic.Field(alias="...")`:

```py
import pydantic

class Tags(pydantic.BaseModel):
    commit : str = pydantic.Field(alias="mlflow.source.git.commit")

data = {
  "mlflow.source.git.commit": "fbe812fe",
  "other.key": "other.value"
}

t = Tags(**data)
```